# Frame rate when using requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript, frame-rate, requestanimationframe

I am trying to explore animation with javascript and decided to make a small game that just involved getting a player to jump over obstacles as they came towards them.  It seems to work ok (although the code is a bit of a mess).  My only issue is that when the player tries to jump the obstacle the frame rate of the animation dips substantially; from about 60fps to 40fps.  I have no idea how to stop this from happening despite looking around ... my CPU barely registers a difference so I'm a bit stumped.  Could anyone tell me how I should approach using `requestAnimationFrame()` as opposed to `setInterval()` which is what I was using before.

Here is the very rough outline of what I have so far: http://embracelondon.com/file_host/g-cycling/index-2.html

Comment: In Firefox, I don't notice any delay in animation. Different browsers handle graphics rendering differently, so often it makes more sense to observe best practices than to try and streamline for speed because what runs quickly in one browser may run slowly in the next.

Comment: I'm running Chrome and it definitely lags on jumping.  I'll keep looking into it ...